# How to call a fake function in Angular 9 component unit test

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, mocking, stub

I have an angular component containing two methods

```
class MyComponent {

    constructor() {
     ...
    }

    loadDataSource() {
     ...
    }
    
    runFilter() {
      //some other logic here
      this.loadDataSource();
    }
}
```

And I have a unit test

```
describe('running filters', () => {
      beforeEach(() => {
        component.runFilter();
        const spy = jasmine.createSpyObj(['loadDataSource']);
        spy.loadDataSource.and.callFake(function() { });
      });
     
      it('should call load data source', () => {
        expect(component.loadDataSource).toHaveBeenCalled();
      });
 });
```

However, this seems to still call the actual implementation of loadDataSource when runFilter is called, instead of the empty fake function I provided.

How may I test that loadDataSource method was called when I call runFilter, without actually invoking the actual implementation? The reason for doing so is I do not want any of the logic for loadDataSource invoked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
 describe('running filters', () => {
          beforeEach(() => {
            spyOn(component, 'loadDataSource').and.callFake();
          });
         
          it('should call load data source', () => {
            component.runFilter();
            expect(component.loadDataSource).toHaveBeenCalled();
          });
     });
```

Comment: Seems to still be executing the actual loadDataSource method, even when I move the runFilter function into the it clause.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like I had forgotten to use the spyOn method.